# Enviar arquivo utilizando HttpPost - ADVPL

Tags: advpl

Estou tentando enviar um arquivo xml utilizando HttpPost.

```
cUrl := "www.test.com"
cPostParms := 'mod=Upload'
cGetParms:=""
cHeadRet := ""
aHeadOut := {User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Protheus '+GetBuild()+'}

HttpPost(cUrl, cGetParms, cPostParms, nTimeOut, aHeadOut, @cHeadRet)
```

Eu não posso utilizar HTTPPostXml, pois no meu caso necessito enviar uma flag no header e este outro método não permite.

Nesse link abaixo diz que é possível realizar o envio através do HttpPost, mas não explica

http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/HTTPPostXml

Alguém saberia?

Obrigado

Comment: A documentação não é das melhores, mais veja se [isso](http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/HTTPPost) lhe ajuda.

Comment: Essa documentação do TDN não tem exemplo para envio de arquivo.

Comment: Não deveria passar o XML no body do Post? (cPostParams)

Comment: Já tentei, mas parece que o Protheus não está montando adequadamente.

Answer (score 1):

Para o uso da função `HTTPPost()` para envio de um arquivo XML, inicialmente o arquivo XML deve ser carregado para a memória em uma variável caractere, que deve ser especificada como parâmetro em `cPostParms` -- isso faz com que o conteúdo a ser postado vá no "corpo" do *Post*. Você pode ler o arquivo do disco usando por exemplo a função `Memoread()`.

```
cPostPArms := Memoread('\xml\MyXmlFile.xml')
```

E, no array `aHeadOut`, você deve acrescentar o header informando que você está enviando um XML : Antes de fazer o post, execute:

```
aadd(aHeadOut,"Content-Type: text/xml")
```

Referências:

http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/MemoRead

Comment: O meu problema é enviar o conteúdo no "Body" e como envio outros parâmetros deve ser aadd(aHeadOut,"Content-Type: form-data")

Comment: Dependendo de como o seu servidor HTTP está esperando eu vai interrpretar este POST, pode ser necessário enviar mais de um Header  -- como por exemplo "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"